# Redirect to a specific tab in a page after node submit

Tags: forms, redirection

I'm working on Drupal 8.9.6.

I'm trying to redirect users to a particular page after they add a node. I can do that without any problem, by adding the following information in the form's URL:

```
/node/add/author/edit?destination=/author-list
```

However, when I try to have a specific **tab** of the destination page opened, as follows:

```
/node/add/author/edit?destination=/author-list#tab2
```

It directly redirects me to `/author-list`, ignoring the `#tab2` part. While if I enter in the browser `/author-list#tab2` I get the `/author-list` page with the `#tab2` active without problem.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most if not all browsers strip the hash (fragment) and this information is lost so you can't rely on hash being in the URL.

[RFC 3986 states:](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

> the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme. Although
> this separate handling is often perceived to be a loss of
> information, particularly for accurate redirection of references as
> resources move over time, it also serves to prevent information
> providers from denying reference authors the right to refer to
> information within a resource selectively.

**Possible workaround:**
Create a hidden input field *url_fragment* and make sure it passes as a URL parameter (&url_fragment=hashvalue). Have some javascript execute on load of this page and if it finds the url_fragment in the URL make it do a scrollTop and opening of the specific tab.

Here is a question and answer that does the [scrollTop if the urlParemeter EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279398/scroll-top-according-to-url-parameter).  You need to modify this script to get the actual value and also click the Tab.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Just take into consideration that you cannot use to pass the parameter '?' and '=', but the url-encode value for those characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940414/url-include-a-parameter-inside-a-destination-query